# trying to send data to mongoDB from angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to save data in mongoDB from angular.
My data became from angular page to node.js page and from their I want to save the data in mongoDB.
I sent the data I want to save to the controller.
and my schema cams from localhost:8080/activities
thanks,

my angular look like that:

```
 <html ng-app="addActivityApp">
     <body ng-controller="activityController">
     <h1 class="text-center">Add Activity</h1>
            <form class="form-group" ng-submit="createActivity()">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title"></input>
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" type="number" placeholder="Age" ng-model="age" min="0" max="16"></input>
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
                 <textarea class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="description"></textarea>
                 <br>
                 <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Themes:</label>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send"></input>
            </form> 
        <script src="js/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="js/addController.js"></script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

and my controller looks like that:

```
var addActivityApp = angular.module('addActivityApp',[]);

var model = {};

addActivityApp.controller('activityController',function($scope) {
    $scope.addActivityApp = model;
});

addActivityApp.run(function($http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:3000/activities").success(function(data){
addActivityApp.createActivity= function($scope){
    var activity = new Activity();
    activity.title = $scope.title;
    activity.age = $scope.age;
    activity.description = $scope.description;
    activity.theme = $scope.theme;
    activity.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.activities.push(result);
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.age = '';
      $scope.description = '';
      $scope.theme = '';
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I read about it and I can't understand what I did wrong

**localhost:3000/activities**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Activity = require('./activity');

exports.getData = function(req, res){
    Activity.find({},function(err, docs){
        console.log("docs "+docs);
        res.json(docs);
        return;
    });
}
```

Comment: Add your nodejs code here

Comment: of my schema? or my get to the page?

Comment: this one http://localhost:3000/activities

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about angularjs, but there is a nodejs module that you could include in your project for mongodb https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb.

Using it is as simple as:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert      = require('assert');

/**
 * save array of json objects to mongodb
 * @param issues
 */
Mongo.saveToMongo = function (issues) {

    // Use connect method to connect to the Server
    MongoClient.connect(mongourl, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected successfully to Mongo");

        // Get the issues collection
        var collection = db.collection('issues');

        console.log("Inserting issues");

        // insert all issues retrieved
        collection.insertMany(issues, function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            console.log("Inserted new issues");
            db.close();
        });
    });
}
```

At the very least you could use it to retro fit your own angular connection.